# PHP - convert yyyy-mm-dd to Month, Year format i.e, ( 2013-01-12 to Jan 2013 )

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-formatting, date-conversion

I get the date in the variable `date` as

```
    $date = "<?php echo $projects->dob;?>" ;  //where let dob=2013-01-12
```

I want to convert this into **`Jan 2013`** format. How to convert in php?

Comment: Did you er, skip the [PHP Manual page on Dates](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) whilst searching for how to format dates in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

do:

```
echo date('M Y', strtotime($your_date));
```

see: [Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$dob = '2013-01-12';
echo date('M Y', strtotime($dob));

$date = date('M Y', strtotime($projects->dob));
```

Example:

https://ideone.com/tdJl8O

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp = strtotime("2013-01-12");
$formatted = date("M Y", $timestamp);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/Lw2eEq6Q

Answer (score 0):

> echo $date = date("M Y",strtotime($projects->dob)) ;